# How to get full content of description from rss feed in Yahoo! Pipes?

Tags: rss, feed, yahoo-pipes, rss-reader, rss2

I have seen many tutorials and guides under the Question I asked. But I could not solve to get the full content of the below feed.

[local news](http://www.haveeru.com.mv/rss/dhivehi)

I would appreciate the help from anyone with the knowledge using pipes to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe Yahoo Pipes will be able to do that for you. In this case the RSS source feed does not have the "full content" for each news item. It only has the short summary in the `<description>` field. Many sites will have a short summary in `<description>` and the full article in `<content:encoded>`, but this site does not.